# Spring boot Redis cache TTL property change on the fly

Tags: spring-boot, azure, redis, spring-cloud-config, azure-spring-cloud

is it possible to change the TTL property of Redis cache during the runtime if the same property has been changed in app config server? is there a way to automate the process to refresh the Redis instance properties during runtime on the event of config server change?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest property in Config Server, it is recommended to do  it through the client polling method, which can be found at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-config-server#config-server-refresh

Regarding the load to Redis instances, you may need to write some code to send out the event.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).